# svg+jquery, alert function not working when clicked on the created svg

Tags: jquery, svg

This code adds a svg image dynamically when clicked on the component button.After that i am 
trying to pass an alert function to the dynamically created component but it does not respond to the click. please help. i tried to pass the function through it  using id,class,path.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>buttons</title>
<style>
input[type="button"]{ 
color:#050; 
font: old 84% 'trebuchet ms',helvetica,sans-serif; 
background-color:#fed; 
border:1px solid; 
border-color: #696 #363 #363 #696; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<svg  class="svg-main" style="height:60%;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

</svg> 
<input type="button" class="Mouse" value="Cursor"/>
<input type="button" class="Component" value="Resistor"/>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v2.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-svgpan.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var $svg= $('.svg-main');
$(".Component").click(function(){
$(SVG('path'))
.attr('d','M10 15 l15 0 l2.5 -5 l5 10 l5 -10 l5 10 l5 -10 l5 10 l2.5 -5 l15 0')
.attr('fill', 'none')
.attr('stroke', 'black')
.attr('stroke-width', 2)
.attr('stroke-linejoin' , 'bevel')
.attr('id' , 'res')
.appendTo($svg);

});
$("#res").click(function(){
alert("hi");
});
function SVG(tag)
{
return document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',tag);
}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#res` doesn't exist at the time when you bind an event to it.

Use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or bind the event after you create an element.

Delegate:

```
$("svg").on("click", "path", function(){ alert("hi"); });
```

Bind:

```
$(SVG("path")).attr(...).on("click", function(){ alert("hi"); }).appendTo($svg);
```